# HTML: how to set children element width = browser window width?

Tags: html, css

I want to display a children element of my html page all over the browser window.. in other words I would like to enlarge it and keep it the same size the browser window also when it is resized after loading.

I was wondering if I have to move this object outside the parent elements or I can set these properties with css.

At the moment if I set width:100% and height:100%, it fits the parent (of course) and not the window.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is typically better to use relative positioning when possible, and any large child elements should be equal to the parent. But you can always absolutely position it:

```
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:100%;
left:0px;
top: 0px;
```

Comment: this is the only correct answer. Without left:0px and top:0px it doesn't work at all.

Comment: I will note that height:100% is hardly browser-agnostic. I'm pretty sure I've never had trouble in FF or Safari, but I've seen many browsers completely mangle the height calculation. So if you're looking for consistency, you may have to really work at it. Just FYI.

Answer (score 0):

width is easy:

```
width: 100%;
```

for height, you need something like this:

[100% Height Layout Using CSS](http://www.dave-woods.co.uk/?p=144)

Answer (score 0):

Width always aplies regarding to the parent element. You could use absolute positioning to have that particular element "out" of it's parent (regarding positioning and flow, that is), and set it to 100%. Be carefull though, it might no end up where you want it to be visually.

```
.someElement {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}
```

The parent element cannot have "position:relative" specified for this to work.